# How to return Json from Interface method in .NET 5 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, repository-pattern, .net-5

I am using repository pattern in .NET 5 Web API. Usually method in interface will return object or list of objects from DB. But in my case, a stored procedure is returning JSON.

How can I return JSON directly from interface method? Is it good idea or I should ask DBA to modify the stored procedure?

Comment: Is the stored proc return json string? or a json object that you capture in some sort of object on c# side? If it is just plain string data containing json structure, then why cant to use the native string type in c#?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *parse* the JSON and do something with it in your program, you can use one of the JSON packages .NET offers. Personally, I'm old school, Json.Net works fine for me, you can get it via NuGet. So your method could return a `JObject`.

If your don't want to do anything with the JSON other than returning it to someone else, you could just pass it along as a `string`. No point in parsing somthing you have no interest in anyway.